# conditions with Configure::read()

Tags: cakephp, controller

I would like to choose how many views a post must have to be on my "Top Post" widget. To do that, in with my controller i've

```
public function menu() {
    return $this->Post->find('all', array(
                'limit' => 5,
                'order' => array('Post.id' => 'desc'),
                'conditions' => array('Post.hits >= 100'
                 )));
}
```

and it's works perfectly.
Now I wand to change my number (100) by a

```
Configure::read('top_views');
```

But i don't know how to do :/ is there someone who can please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `menu` method to take a parameter with a default value, update the conditions array.

```
public function menu($hits = 100) {
    return $this->Post->find('all', array(
                'limit' => 5,
                'order' => array('Post.id' => 'desc'),
                'conditions' => array('Post.hits >=' => $hits) // here
                 ));
}
```

then you can call it and pass in any value you like:

```
$this->set('top_posts', $this->Post->menu(Configure::read('top_views'));
$more_than_500_hits = $this->Post->menu(500);
```

This assumes your `menu` method is in your `Post` controller, adjust as needed for your own app. Typically this sort of thing should be in the model.